# Why cant go-app-builder find local imports?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am currently writing an application in Go and trying to deploy multiple services. I am running the following command : `gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml app/app.yaml mod1/mod1.yaml`.

The app.yaml file corresponds to the default service and is successfully deployed however the service mod1 returns this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Deployment contains files that cannot be compiled: Compile failed: 2016/07/22 18:17:14 go-app-builder: build timing: 1×compile (53ms total), 0×link (0 total) 2016/07/22 18:17:14 go-app-builder: failed running compile: exit status 1

mod1.go:4: can't find import: "myapp/mod1/web_console"

My-Macbook: myapp$ gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml app/app.yaml mod1/mod1.yaml
```

My file structure is as follows:

- /My_Project

  - /src

    - /myapp

      - /app

        - app.go
        - app.yaml
      - /mod1

        - mod1.go
        - mod1.yaml
        - /web_console

          - web_console.go

**mod1.go :**

```
package mod1

import (
    "myapp/mod1/web_console"
)

func init() {
    // Initializing Web Console establishes connection
    // to the database and also creates routes
    var wc *web_console.WebConsole
    wc = web_console.NewWebConsole(true)
    wc.Configure()
}
```

**mod1.yaml :**

```
module: mod1
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

**app.yaml :**

```
module: default
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /.*
 script: _go_app
```

Thanks for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

Each GAE service/module is standalone and can not access anything **outside** the service/module dir which:

- is the directory where the `.yaml` file exists
- is what's uploaded during deployment
- is considered the "root" directory for that service/module, everything is relative to it

In your particular case you need to make sure no service/module makes references to the parent `myapp` dir (which is nothing but an organisational placeholder for the app stuff, relevant on your side but **with no actual presence on GAE**). I believe your `mod1.go` import should looks like this:

```
package mod1

import (
    "web_console"
)
```

But take it with a grain of salt, I'm not actually familiar with go.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately after changing the import statement I still get the error : can't find import: "web_console" .

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I was using the wrong tool to deploy. I ran the command with `goapp deploy app/app.yaml mod1/mod1.yaml` and was able to successfully deploy the services without issue.

Comment: With your original import statement?

Comment: Yup, didn't change anything. I'm not too sure what's going on so I'm going to dive into the documentation a bit more.